# MATLAB sum of series

Tags: matlab

[image]

I tried to use symsum function and a for loop but the program took to long and crash

```
for n=[100 1000 10000 100000 1000000]
    syms i
    n
    F1 = symsum(sin(i)/cos(i),i,1,n)
end
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: A symbolic function with a million terms? That sounds unreasonable. I don’t think you’re supposed to solve your problem this way. There’s no reason to use symbolic variables for that exercise.

Comment: With `n = 1000000` matlab need `n^2 = 1000000000000` iterations, that's a lot, even for a computer. But noticed that you can greatly reduce the computation time with (for example with n = 100): `S = sum(sum(sin(1:100))./cos(1:100))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
n = 10.^(2:8);
T = zeros(size(n));
for k = 1:length(n)
  tstart = tic;
  sum(sin(1:n(k))).*sum(1./cos(1:n(k)));
  T(k) = toc(tstart);
end
loglog(n,T);
xlabel("n");
ylabel("T(n)");
```

and you will get
[image]